# How do i create a SEO friendly schema in the backend?

Tags: javascript

I need to create a structured snippet in the backend to help search engine bots identify my table, images for featured snippets on the search engines. Need to know, where should I add the structured snippet and how

I have tried adding the data [within meta tags of this page](https://www.vishumoney.com/stores/happyeasygo-coupons), however, it has not taken effect